# iOS | InstantiateViewController vs Init

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I'm not using storyboards. All views and their constraints in code.
So there is any differences between using these two? Maybe performance?

**InstantiateViewController:**

```
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewController")
```

**Initializing new one:**

`let vc = MyViewController()`

Comment: If you are not using storyboard than you will not able to use `storyboard.instantiateViewController`.

Comment: I think it's the same difference between `initWithXibName:bundle:` and `init` alone. I think that by doing all by code you are adding some diffculties (harder to imagine what it looks like in a instant), but else, it shouldn't be that much different.

Comment: I just thought instantiateViewController works like dequeueReusableCell int TableView. And it gives some performance.